# Keep classes assigned with Angular when changing the state

Tags: css, angularjs

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-4" ng-repeat="product in products" ng-click="selectItem($event)"> {{desc(product)}}</div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.selectItem = function (event) {          
  $(event.target).addClass('greenLetter');
}
```

This works, the problem is when I need change state, if I go back to this controller, I miss greenLetter, how can I keep it?

Answer (score 1):

The *Angular way* to do that would be using [`ngClass`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

In the following code, clicking the element will set `selected` to the current product you are repeating over (using `$index`).

`ngClass` will be applied only if the `selected` element is the clicked one.

```
<div class="col-xs-4" 
     ng-class="{'greenLetter': selected == $index}"
     ng-repeat="product in products" 
     ng-click="selectItem($index)">
```

```
$scope.selectItem = function(index) {          
    $scope.selected = index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help me, but with this code every divs have the class.